# Reference request: an interpretation of Euler totient function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\phi$ be the [Euler totient function](https://oeis.org/A000010). Let $A_r$ be the number of coprime pairs of positive integers $a,b$ such that $2a+b=r$, $r \ge 3$. By direct computation, I verified a few examples that $\phi(r) = 2A_r$, $r \ge 3$. Is there a proof of this fact in the literature? Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't answer the question about its appearance in the literature, but the proof turns out to be straightforward: show that the allowable values of $b$ are precisely the positive integers less than $\frac r2$ that are coprime to $r$.

Comment: Perhaps your observation that $$\phi(r)=2 A_r=2 \sum\limits_{\substack{1\le a\le r/2 \\ \gcd(a,r-2 a)=1 }}  1\,,\quad r\ge 3\tag{1}$$ is related to the observation that $$\phi(r)=B_r=\sum\limits_{\substack{1\le a\le r \\ \gcd(a,r-2 a)=1 }} 1\,,\quad r\ge 1\tag{2}$$.